# Why a:hover does not work , if it is not declared in correct order in style sheet?

Tags: css

The hover function only works when the link gets visited. Before the visit the color doesn't change when the link gets hovered.

https://jsfiddle.net/raushankumar0717/xzggq9ex/

```css
a:visited{
color:#ee9a00;
}

a:hover{
color:#ff0000;
}

a:link{
color:#008b45;
}
```

```html
<h3>Testing Link pseudo class workings:</h3>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow">Link</a>
```

Why is correct order of pseudo class declaration is required , I mean when we will hover on link , it should style according to a:hover irrespective of order of declaration.

And also I know order is important as it determines specificity , but I think pseudo class is dynamic state of html element. And when we hover cursor on link ,at that time the state of element  is hover , so it should style according to style rule a:hover irrespective of order.

Comment: because :link is last in your stylesheet... so it hovers, then it realises it's a link

Comment: It _should not_ style irrespective of order of declaration when specificity of rules is the same. If you've the time and interest you should read [the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html) or other articles on CSS specificity and inheritance.

Comment: here every selector have same specificity , so when we hover on the link state of element changes to hover so it should style according to a defined state style i.e. a:hover

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is how CSS works (order is important). For styling links the order for pseudo-classes is:

1. [Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:link) (applied if you have not visited this URL)
2. [Visited](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited) (applied if you've visited the URL the href points to)
3. [Hover](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:hover) (applied if the mouse is hovering over the tag)
4. [Active](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active) (applied if you are interacting with the tag - pressing mouse down, etc)

The reason why order is important is because of [CSS Specificity](https://css-tricks.com/specifics-on-css-specificity/). The rules you've written all have the same specificity, and therefore will be affected by order (rules written last will override earlier written rules).

Note that `:hover` will not work with those using a keyboard. You can provide those users with the same experience by using the `:focus` pseudo-class.

```css
a:link {
  color: blue;
  text-decoration: none;
}

a:visited {
  color: purple;
}

a:hover,
a:focus {
  text-decoration: underline;
}

a:active {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">This is a link</a>
```

Comment: yes order is important(it determines specificity) , but I think pseudo class is dynamic state of html element. And when we hover cursor on link ,at that time state of element <a> is hover , so it should style according to style rule a:hover

Comment: To be a little more specific: Specificity is determined by the selector, order is used to determine a _winner_ if two rules have the same specificity and affect the same elements.

Comment: @RaushanKumar These particular pseudo classes do reference a dynamic state of the element, but CSS rules for specificity will always apply, despite your most vehement objections as to how you think it should work.

Comment: yes order determine winner if selectors selecting same dom element. But here my confusion is hover is different state of element <a> , so it should style according to its state.

Comment: so if I declare on bottom a {color: grey;} then link it should be grey . But it is not ?

Comment: @RaushanKumar in that case, no, `a { color: grey; }` has a lower specificity `0.0.0.1` than the other rules `0.0.1.1`, and therefore will be overridden.

Comment: Thank you very much, I get it. One Last confusion when we hover on link state of element changes to hover so it should style according to a defined state style i.e. a:hover

Comment: @RaushanKumar I realize this part is a little hard to grasp, but you will get it soon. When you hover on the link, you are indicating to the browser to apply the `a:hover` style to the link (and that happens, as you say). _However_, the part you are missing is that **if there is another rule that has a higher specificity or precedence over the :hover rule and affects the same properties (e.g. `color` in this instance), then that rule will apply and override the hover style**. Just like the first comment on your question by @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs stated.

Comment: Thank You very much

Comment: Here is a way to remember the order: **L**o**V**e **HA**te
source: [link](https://css-tricks.com/remember-selectors-with-love-and-hate/)

Answer (score 0):

Your code order should some thing like this

```css
a:link{
color:#008b45;
}

a:visited{
color:#ee9a00;
}

a:hover{
color:#ff0000;
}
```

```html
<h3>Testing Link pseudo class workings:</h3>
<a href="https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow">Link</a>
```

Comment: I dont understand why this order is important

Comment: because css meaning cascade style sheet and parsing top to down and if some style after another ,The last style apply

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare CSS directives in the right order. Hover directive should be declared last to have any effect.

```
a:visited{
  color:#ee9a00;
}

a:link{
  color:#008b45;
}

a:hover{
  color:#ff0000;
}
```

Check out this example: https://jsfiddle.net/xzggq9ex/3/

Good luck :)

Answer (score 0):

It's because of the CSS Cascade rules. If several rules with the same property can apply to the same element, and they come from the same origin and have the same specificity, then the property that comes last in the code "wins".

In your example, all selectors are from the same origin (author styles) and have the same specificity (0-1-1). So if a link is not visited *and* it is hovered, it is matched by the 2nd and the 3rd selectors, and the 3rd selectors wins. If it is visited, then it is matched by the 1st and the 2nd selector, and the 2nd selectors wins.

That is why you should order link pseudo classes so that the "non-interactive" ones (:link and :visited) would not "win" over the "interactive" ones (":hover", ":active" and ":focus"). The "link, visited, hover, focus, active" order is the common good practice.

Alternatively, you can combine pseudo classes, e.g. `a:visited:hover`, and even set different styling for hovering visited and non-visited links.

Answer (score 0):

a:link{color: #008b45;} a:visited{color: #ee9a00;} a:hover{font-size:20px; color: #ff0000;}

#### Link class working by test:

Click Me!!!!

Answer (score -1):

Link is for pages you haven't yet visited, and takes precedence over hover as it is the last item in the CSS. You can force hover with the CSS below, but there isn't any real benefit:

```
a:hover{
    color:#ff0000 !important;
}
```

Edit: Lots of down votes, I didn't recommend it...

Comment: Would not recommend using `!important` for this.

Answer (score -1):

You better read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_pseudo_classes.asp) before asking these kind of basics.

```
/* unvisited link */
a:link {
    color: #FF0000;
}
```